# Regex matching for value between two patterns doesn't return all instances when the values are consecutive

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all instance of a number within an equation. And for that, I wrote this python script:

```
re.findall(fr"([\-\+\*\/\(]|^)({val})([\-\+\*\/\)]|$)", equation)
```

Now, when I give it this: `20+5-20`, and search for `20`, the output is as expected: `[('', '20', '+'), ('-', '20', '')]`
But, when I simply do `20+20-5`, it doesn't work anymore and I only get the first instance: `[('', '20', '+')]`

I don't understand why, it's not even a problem of `20` being at start and end, for example, this `5-20*4-20/3` will still match `20` very well. It just doesn't work when the value is repeated consecutively

how do I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: What is `{val}` supposed to mean here?

Comment: this is python string formatting using f-strings, just ignore it and think of {val} as 20 in this example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your pattern initially does not work for `20+20-5` is that the character class after matching the first occurrence of 20 actually consumes the `+`

After consuming it, for the second occurrence of 20 right after it, this part of the pattern `[\-\+\*\/\(]|^)` can not match as there is no character to match with the character class, and it is not at the start of the string.

Using 20 for example at the place of `{val}` you can use lookarounds, which do not consume the value but only assert that it is present.

Note that you don't have to escape the values in the character class, and for the last assertion you don't have to add another non capture group.

```
(?:(?<=[-+*/(])|^)20(?=[-+*/)]|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dFXhl0/1)

```
import re

strings = [
    "20+5-20",
    "20+20-5"
]
val = 20
pattern = fr"(?:(?<=[-+*/(])|^){val}(?=[-+*/)]|$)"

for equation in strings:
    print(re.findall(pattern, equation))
```

Output

```
['20', '20']
['20', '20']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest just searching for all numbers (integer + decimal) in your expression, and then filtering for certain values:

```py
inp = "20+5-20*3.20"
matches = re.findall(r'\d+(?:\.\d+)?', inp)
matches = [x for x in matches if x == '20']
print(matches)  # ['20', '20']
```

Every number in your formula should *only* be surrounded by either arithmetic symbols, parentheses, or whitespace, all of which are non word characters.

Comment: this works! but the problem is that I am allowing for non-integers too (eg 3.20 shouldn't match, but it does it If used \b). On this note, how come yours works but mine doesn't when the idea is exactly the same?

Comment: @RRR Your current code has several syntax problems.  Given your new revealed requirements, I suggest just finding all numbers, and then filtering that list for the values you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer, still not sure how correct it is or why it's working and mine doesn't :/

```
re.findall(fr"(?:(?<=[\=\-\+\*\/\(])|^)({val})(?:(?=[\=\-\+\*\/\)])|$)", equation
```

basically, performing backward lookup and forward lookup to see if the value is between operations